# How do i display a video using IBM Watson Assistant

Tags: chatbot, watson

I have create a Chat bot using IBM Watson Assistant and i need to load an video for some responses. How do i embed a video into the chat bots' response?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use HTML tags to embed a video into the response box as shown below:

[image]

Please note that HTML tags won't work in the Try It Out panel but will definitely be rendered in the application.

If you are looking for dynamic content, then you will have to pass context to the application side and then render video from there.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Works for me. This helps me a lot.

Comment: @RiyaMRoy I need to add a calendar picker. I am giving as response below code :
<form >
  <input type="date" id="birthday" name="birthday">
</form>
It is showing on the IBM chatbot when I run. But after selecting the date, how do I store the selected date value in a context variable to use it further. Please help.

Answer (score -1):

Appreciate to suggest how to play the video on Alexa Echo Show device too.IBM  Watson Assistant is being used in the backend. While using your mentioned  HTML tags to embed a video into the response box as described by you in IBM Watson Assistant. It is perfectly working in user interface chat window. But while testing it on Alexa Echo Show device. There is challenge to play the video.