# IBM watson add video

Tags: chatbot, ibm-watson, slack

I would like to add a Video as a Response to my IBM Watson. 
As suggested in a previous Topic  [How do i display a video using IBM Watson Assistant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50409269/how-do-i-display-a-video-using-ibm-watson-assistant?answertab=votes#tab-top) I entered following code line as a text into my Response:

```
    <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/AnmWwudeqfM" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

After that I integrated my Watson chatbot into the application Slack in order to see the Video.
Instead of showing the Video as a Response it is showing only the code line. 
How can I embed a Video into IBM Watson and Show it in my application Slack?

Comment: The issue is where you are rendering the HTML, not really a Watson Assistant issue.

Comment: It is not possible to use HTML in Slack responses. You need to use Slack's specific syntax to add links and formatting to your messages. Please check our the excellent documentation for details. https://api.slack.com/docs/message-formatting

Answer (score 0):

Slack doesn't offer displaying videos as a response to chatbots. Alternatively add the URL of the video as a response. It's like how ChatGPT displays the answer, just text with no media at all.