# How to add video as a response in IBM watson assistant in 30 days trial version of ibm watson?

Tags: chatbot, ibm-watson

I am creating a chatbot for my application. I want to show video as response to particular question. I am using 30 days trial version of ibm watson.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this only with ***iframe*** tag. Please check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50409269/how-do-i-display-a-video-using-ibm-watson-assistant) for a similar question.